# sql date format "2019-10-30", "2019/10/30", "10-30-2019" and "10/30/2019"

Tags: sql, mariadb

I think it's no doubt that in sql `"2019-10-30"` is valid date format, and looks like `"2019/10/30"` accepted as well.

What about `"10-30-2019"` and `"10/30/2019"`?

I tried them in mariaDB and they're wrong format, but somehow I think I did see them in some sql tables. Please help me clarify the date format. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB, the format for dates is `yyyy-mm-dd`. But MariaDB is quite lax and other formats are accepted; from [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date-and-time-literals/):

> A `DATE` string is a string in one of the following formats: `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'`. Note that any punctuation character can be used as delimiter. All delimiters must consist of 1 character. Different delimiters can be used in the same string. Delimiters are optional (but if one delimiter is used, all delimiters must be used).
>
> A `DATE` literal can also be an integer, in one of the following formats: `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD`.
>
> All the following `DATE` literals are valid, and they all represent the same value:
>
> `'19940101'`
>
> `'940101'`
>
> `'1994-01-01'`
>
> `'94/01/01'`
>
> `'1994-01/01'`
>
> `'94:01!01'`
>
> `19940101`
>
> `940101`

So, for the examples that you provided:

```
2019-10-30    -- ok: default format
2019/10/30    -- ok: format with alternative delimiter
10-30-2019    -- NOT ok
10/30/2019    -- NOT ok
```

You can translate a string to a date with function `str_to_date()`.

```
str_to_date('10-30-2019', '%m-%d-%Y')
str_to_date('10/30/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: one more question, when I try this `str_to_date("10/31/2019", "%m/%d/%y")` - note that lower case `%y`, I get wrong result `2020-10-31`. what's the difference of `%Y` and `%y` here?

Comment: @JamesWang: upper y stands for 4-digits year, lower is for 2 digits (if you give 4 digits to the lower y, it takes the first 2 digits and ignores the rest, hence the result that you get).

Answer (score 0):

What you are really doing is converting from a string representation of a date to an internal date time representation or data type. The format you are referring to is [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The ISO date (2019-10-30 with hyphens or parentheses) format is usually the native or default string conversion that most databases use, that's why those formats work even if you don't specify the conversion. If you intend to convert from other formats you probably would need to specify them. Your default representation for your local settings might work too, but that depends on the specific database.